# Record screen with sound in İpad Pro(11-inch) simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

As the title suggests, I want to record the screen with the iPad's own record button. Currently, I can record in silent mode. I received information saying "it does capture sound, you just need to enable it." However, I can't find where to enable it.[image: de]